# CSS3 animation - smooth infinite cycle

Tags: css, css-animations

I've made a small background animation where a div changes color over time.
It works smoothly, but when it gets to 100% it jumps straight to 0% without any transition.
I've searched on google and tried different ways of doing the animation, but I've been unable to get a fluid "restart" if the animation.

What am I missing?

```
-webkit-animation: pulsate 20s infinite;
animation: pulsate 20s infinite;
-moz-animation: pulsate 20s infinite;

            @-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
                0% {background: @black}
                25% {background: @red}
                50% {background: @blue}
                75% {background: @orange}
                100% {background: @green}
            }


            @keyframes pulsate {
                0% {background: @black}
                25% {background: @red}
                50% {background: @blue}
                75% {background: @orange}
                100% {background: @green}
            }

            @-moz-keyframes pulsate {
                0% {background: @black}
                25% {background: @red}
                50% {background: @blue}
                75% {background: @orange}
                100% {background: @green}
            }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just have to fix your frames in another way : make the `from` (0%) and `to` (100%) values the same:

```css
html, body {   
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    -webkit-animation: pulsate 20s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: pulsate 20s linear infinite;
    animation: pulsate 20s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {background: black}
    20% {background: red}
    40% {background: blue}
    60% {background: orange}
    80% {background: green}
    100% {background: black}
}
@-moz-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {background: black}
    20% {background: red}
    40% {background: blue}
    60% {background: orange}
    80% {background: green}
    100% {background: black}
}
@keyframes pulsate {
    0% {background: black}
    20% {background: red}
    40% {background: blue}
    60% {background: orange}
    80% {background: green}
    100% {background: black}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is the `animation-direction` property, which could be set to `alternate` to have it run back and forth instead of jumping back to 0% again.

```
-webkit-animation: pulsate 20s infinite alternate;
animation: pulsate 20s infinite alternate;
-moz-animation: pulsate 20s infinite alternate;
```

EDIT: zessx just posted a fiddle before removing it again. I just updated that with the `alternate` option. Works fine. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FZg2D/1/)

Comment: This method works well, although the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/FZg2D/1/) does not.