# Firefox vs. Chrome Fade-In animation

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, animation

I've added tabs to my site using CSS and according to this demo:

http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/pure-css-tab-with-fade-animation/index4.html

However, chrome and firefox behave differently in regards to the animation.
Once you revisit a tab, firefox doesn't play the Fade-In animation again - chrome does.
How can I tell firefox to play the animation again?

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/h5W33/

important part:

```
.tabs label {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

[id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content], [id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] > div {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Paste your code here or show a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: you might have to restart the animations with js http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 animation - smooth infinite cycle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403002/css3-animation-smooth-infinite-cycle)